# RequireJS Module Versioning

Tags: requirejs, commonjs

I've been creating modules using RequireJS with the following pattern:

```
// File: fancy-function.js
define(function() {
  return function() {
    return foobar;
  }
});
```

Then loading them as follows:

```
// File: main.js
require(["fancy-function"], function(fancyFunction) {
  alert("Fancy function: " + fancyFunction());
});
```

**Is there a way to version my modules?**  In particular, I want to

- Assign each module I create a version number
- On calling `require`, require either a minimum or particular version

So imagine I start with version 0.1 of fancy-function.js and am in the process of updating it to version 0.2.  I make a change to main.js that needs version 0.2.  I'd like to be able to guarantee I have at least that minimum version before loading the module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion ?

The trick is to assign the returned value of require.config to a predefined user var (in this sample *reqOne* and *reqTwo*), and then, use those vars as the *require* function, depending on the version you want to use.

Comment: Multiversioning is actually for those who want two different versions of the same module.  It isn't really version support; rather, it is showing how to modify the context on-the-fly.  I don't think the documentation shows what I'm looking for - I'll probably have to write a plugin to get the functionality I want.